# Modal pop-ups flashing to the side of the screen. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, modal-dialog

I built a form that calculates numbers entered into the form fields for credit card rewards. The form utilizes modal pop-ups to communicate results with the user.

The problem is that all of the modals flash to the right-side of the screen for a split second when the modals are activated and closed. I'm not sure what needs to be changed to make them appear in the center of the screen 100% of the time.

What do I need to change to make it work?

[Github Code](https://github.com/ZacharyFoxLuke/Worth-It)

[Live Version](https://zacharyfoxluke.github.io/Worth-It/Framework/index_NEW.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as changes to outside sources will make this question become outdated and irrelevant for both this site and future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your animation keyframes with this

```
@-webkit-keyframes popperIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.06);
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes popperIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.06);
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes popperIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.06);
    }

    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes popperOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.15);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes popperOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    40% {
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.15);
    }
}

@keyframes popperOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    40% {
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.05);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.15);
    }
}
```

It will defiantly work